# Mapping of <ctrl-#> characters

Tags: vi, vim

I've been trying to map certain sequences to parenthesis/bracket completion without any success.  I've been trying the following commands to map certain control sequences but they don't seem to work.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

:imap <ctrl-9> ( )hha 
:imap <ctrl-(> ( )hha

Answer (score 2):

Vim doesn't always support all the `ctrl-` key combinations, and they can also end up being transmitted as something else because of your terminal. The easiest way to enter these is to type `:map` literally, then press <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd>, and then press <kbd>CTRL+9</kbd> (or whatever number you want). If vim is able to recognize `ctrl+9` then the correct code for `ctrl+9` will be inserted.